RDS SQL Server unreachable after scaling up instance class
I have a RDS SQL Server (2022) which I was able to connect to without issue. We started to see degraded performance due to RAM constraints, so I figured it would be safe to increase the instance class to handle this problem (db.m5.large -> db.r5.large). This is an operation I have done with Postgres on RDS many times without issue.
Upon completion of this upgrade, the instance is no longer reachable- I cannot connect using any method, and it behaves as though it is a TCP/IP error.
Restoring a backup to a new instance of the same class, same issue connecting.
Upon downgrading the instance class back to the m5, the server goes back to behaving as expected.
Is there some nuance with RDS or MSSQL which I am not aware of which is causing this behavior? What process should I be following to change instance classes?
